# CSS - main content have pattern, child elements need to be transperent

Tags: css

Code:

```
<div id="slider_footer">

    <div class="slider_tabs container clearfix" >

        <span role="winter" class="current">
            <div class="slider_tabs_naslov">Zima</div>
            <div class="slidet_tabs_tekst">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</div>
        </span>

        <span role="summer">
            <div class="slider_tabs_naslov">Leto</div>
            <div class="slidet_tabs_tekst">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</div>
        </span>

        <span role="spring">
            <div class="slider_tabs_naslov">Prolece</div>
            <div class="slidet_tabs_tekst">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</div>
        </span>

        <span role="fall">
            <div class="slider_tabs_naslov">Jesen</div>
            <div class="slidet_tabs_tekst">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</div>
        </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**slider_footer** is container element and **slider_tabs** is child element. **slider_footer** is covering image with 100% width (it is absolute positioned over image) and this element have **png** image pattern. **slider_tabs** needs to be transparent and show image. How can I override pattern from parent element (**slider_footer**) and make **slider_tabs** transparent.

Comment: Please post your CSS instead of describing it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
div#slider_footer {
    background: url(pattern.png);
}
div#slider_footer div.slider_tabs span {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);  /* R, G, B, Opacity */
}
```

It lets #slider_footer have your pattern bg
and your  content have a color with opacity, which remains your text fully visible.